# Error Message: 'numpy.dtype[bool_]' during Ipyrad Assembly of RADseq Data

Tags: metadata, bioinformatics, phylogeny, nomachine

I was hoping that someone could help me alleviate the one issue I have been having during my ipyrad assembly. I am working with RADseq data and my error occurs only during Step 7 of (Filtering and Formatting) of the pipeline. I get an error message that says 'numpy.dtype[bool_]' and it closes the connection. Has anyone ran into this issue? Any recommendations? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried updating my current version of conda to the latest version. For the last two days, the 'solving environment' aspect of the conda update has been stuck in the same exact position. It has no problem acquiring the metadata for the package but it has been 'solving environment' for an extremely long time. If it doesn't finish updating conda in a day or two, then I have no idea how to kill the update.
I'm pretty stuck with alleviating my ipyrad issues. I am relatively new to bioinformatics so any help/recommendations would be appreciated. Thank you.